# Why are copy/paste/select all options disabled in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I use this code to change the frame of an uitextview but the options of copy/paste etc. are disabled afterwards.

```
CGRect viewFrame = poemcomment.frame;
viewFrame.size.height = 144;
viewFrame.origin.y = 513;
poemcomment.frame = viewFrame;
poemcomment.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
poemcomment.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
poemcomment.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have look to the following SO post that describe the way to enable cpoy/paste options with input controls by subclassing the UITextView and implementation the below functions

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

> [@mrueg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166198/mrueg) asked the same and also provided
>   the solution,

[Enable copy and paste on UITextField without making it editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920541/enable-copy-and-paste-on-uitextfield-without-making-it-editable)

Comment: i have found the post you specified