# Enable Copy Paste Option of UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have enable the  set editable property yes of UItextview and i am able to copy past the text while running in simulator.But i am not able to copy paste the text in iPhone device ..Please someone sort out my problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try once by double tap on UITextView for copy and paste.
Also check this link [Enable copy and paste on UITextField without making it editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920541/enable-copy-and-paste-on-uitextfield-without-making-it-editable)
hope this may help you.

Comment: By double tapping copy option is coming but  not the paste option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "paste" method?
Here is an example from the iOS Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard *gpBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSArray *pbType = [NSArray arrayWithObject:ColorTileUTI];
    ColorTile *theTile = [self colorTileForOrigin:currentSelection];
    if (theTile == nil && [gpBoard containsPasteboardTypes:pbType]) {
        NSData *tileData = [gpBoard dataForPasteboardType:ColorTileUTI];
        ColorTile *theTile = (ColorTile *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver     unarchiveObjectWithData:tileData];
        if (theTile) {
            theTile.tileOrigin = self.currentSelection;
            [tiles addObject:theTile];
            CGRect tileRect = [self rectFromOrigin:currentSelection inset:TILE_INSET];
            [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:tileRect];
        }
    }
}
```