# How to make a textField or UILabel by long press,make it can be "copy", but not to edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, long-press

As the title, how to make a `UILabel` or `UITextField` long press can be copy, but not edit?

I show the pic:

[image: This is the copy state]

I have tested the `UITextField`, even so long press it can make it be copy, but it also can be edit, such as delete some words, or can add some words, which is not required.

Comment: how about textField.enabled = NO; with UILabel i don't think it's possible

Comment: for UILabel https://github.com/alexandreos/UILabel-Copyable

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found for UILabel: https://github.com/alexandreos/UILabel-Copyable

install via cocoapods:

`pod 'UILabel+Copyable', '~> 1.0.1'`

Comment: you see my question have cursor,can choose words.

Comment: check this out:[Enable copy and paste on UITextField without making it editable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920541/enable-copy-and-paste-on-uitextfield-without-making-it-editable) and this [How to disable UITextField editing but still accept touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116969/how-to-disable-uitextfield-editing-but-still-accept-touch)