# Disable keyboard, enable copy/paste function - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

Is there a way to have a UITextfield where users can only copy/paste in swift?

So the keyboard would be disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable copy and paste on UITextField without making it editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920541/enable-copy-and-paste-on-uitextfield-without-making-it-editable)

Comment: @the4kman that's an objective-C solution and was written eight years ago.